# How to handle functions inside an Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, javascript-objects

I am trying to handle an simple personalAccount object in javascript. I have created some function inside objects key but
when i'm trying to console my accountBalance funtion it not showing desire output.

I'm trying income and expense data inside accountSummary key it should me (totalIncome - totalExpense) = desire output, but it gives NaN in my terminal.

`

```
const personAccount = {
    firstName: 'Prashant',
    lastName: 'Singh',
    incomes: [20000, 30000, 40000],
    expenses: [],
    totalIncome: function() {
        return this.incomes.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr,0);
    },
    totalExpense: function() {
        return this.expenses.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr,0);
    },
    accountInfo: function () {
        return `First Name: ${this.firstName}, Last Name: ${this.lastName}, Total Income: ${this.totalIncome()}, Total Expense: ${this.totalExpense()}, Account Balance: ${this.totalIncome() - this.totalExpense()}`
    },
    addIncome: function (income) {
        this.incomes.push(income);
        return this.incomes;
    },
    addExpense: function (expenses){
        this.expenses.push(expenses);
        return this.expenses;
    },
    accountBalance: function () {
        return this.totalIncome() - this.totalExpense();
    },
    accountSummary: function () {
        return `First Name: ${this.firstName}, Last Name: ${this.lastName}, Balance: ${this.accountBalance()}`
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Please show us how you use your code, how you call your functions. Because for me, the code works

Comment: Might be a better idea to make a class for this, then instantiate it with mr. Singh's data, so there's just a single prototype with all the functions that every instance uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work fine, It's all about how you are accessing it. Here is the working demo, Kindly review and try to find the root cause.

```js
const personAccount = {
  incomes: [20000, 30000, 40000],
  expenses: [],
  totalIncome: function() {
    return this.incomes.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr,0);
  },
  totalExpense: function() {
    return this.expenses.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr,0);
  },
  accountBalance: function () {
    return this.totalIncome() - this.totalExpense();
  }
};

console.log(personAccount.accountBalance());
```